# Colorful tab for IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer

any solution for IE 7 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1368

Comment: Why not switch to firefox?

Comment: Doesn't IE8 have this built-in?

Comment: Yes, IE8 has this feature built in. Never heard about such a plugin for IE7

Comment: @Phosi Totally agree, since the question pretty much proves that you are trying to browse easier and faster (and not that you're a web developer fixing IE bugs), I recommended you download either Google Chrome, Firefox or Opera.

Comment: @onno, Slacker: This extension just colors the tabs, it doesn't group them (which IE 8 does—and IE 8 colors the groups, not individual tabs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[IE8 Tab Grouping](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/30/ie8-tab-grouping.aspx)** is what you're looking for (not available in IE7):

[image]

if you're looking for some more powerful IE addons, get Bayden Systems' **[IEToys](http://www.bayden.com/ietoys/)**.

Comment: Tab grouping colors the *groups*, not the individual tabs. Ungrouped tabs are uncolored, as usual.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to [Internet Explorer 8](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/worldwide-sites.aspx)